# force z-Range in gnuplot - pm3d

Tags: gnuplot

i have some 2d data files, that i want to plot with gnuplot. Unfortunatly, the values of the files are not in the same range. howevery, i need the z axis to be the same. here is my code:

```
set pm3d map interpolate 1,1

splot "Diff.txt" matrix using (1+$1):(1+$2):3 

unset key

set terminal png font arial 20 size 1200, 1200  


set palette defined (  0 "blue", 8 "white", 16 "red")
set zrange [-0.04:0.04]


set output "Diff.png"
replot
```

i get a z-axis from -0.015 - 0.02. is there any way to "force" gnuplot to use the given range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The color range is defined by the `cbrange` and is not the same as the `zrange`. Use:

```
set terminal pngcairo font "Arial,20" size 1200,1200
set output 'Diff.png'

set pm3d map interpolate 1,1
unset key
set palette defined (  0 "blue", 8 "white", 16 "red")

set cbrange [-0.04:0.04]
splot "Diff.txt" matrix using (1+$1):(1+$2):3
```

BTW: You should use the `pngcairo` terminal, which gives better images than the `png` terminal (uses libgd). If your gnuplot version is not linked to libgd, then the `png` terminal is linked to `pngcairo`. But in general those two are different terminals.